# How to prevent "Error: $rootScope:infdig" when different value each time is intended behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a page using AngularJS(with Aria, Animate, Material, Messages, Sanitize and Route), everyting is working fine but I have a bit of a problem. Angular likes to throw "Error: $rootScope:infdig" when the value returned by function is different every time the page is refreshed but that is what one function I wrote is exactly meant to do.

The code:

```
<script>

    angular.module('tht', ['ngMaterial', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria'])

    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.version = '0.1';
        $rootScope.name = 'tht';
        $rootScope.author = 'D3add3d';
        $rootScope.year = '2016';
        $scope.jokes = ["We ate a bunch of doritos and now the page is blank...", 
                        "Sometimes it just looks like this...", 
                        "Kappa, Kappa, Kappa, Kappa...", 
                        "This text changes every time I refresh the page, weird huh o_O", 
                        "We are out of doritos :-/", 
                        "Powered by your satisfaction... wait", 
                        "Instead of working on this page, I'm writing these jokes #procrastination", 
                        "Have a hug or two *hugs*", 
                        "<3", "<3~~~", 
                        "This joke is so simple... return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];", 
                        "Go eat some chocolate, it helps ;)", 
                        "I love you all :-* <3", "[~~HUG~~]", 
                        "[?BUG?]"];
        $scope.randomJoke = function() {
            return $scope.jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.jokes.length)]; //function that returns different value (almost) every time it is called
        }
    }]);

</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" ng-hide>

    <header>Hello, this is <b>{{name}}</b>, version <b>{{version}}</b>
    <article><br>{{randomJoke()}}</article> <!-- THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE ERROR -->
    </header>
    <footer>&copy; <b>{{author}}</b>, {{year}}</footer>

</div>
```

So the question is: Is there any way to avoid this error in a case where I want the value to be different every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work, because of how Interpolation Bindings `{{ }}` are evaluated.

Interpolation Bindings are not evaluated once per page reload.  They are evaluated every `$digest` cycle, to determine if their value needs to be updated, which is the cornerstone of how angular two way binding works.  Unfortunately, functions which are executed inside an Interpolation Binding cause another `$digest` cycle to fire, in order to determine if the function call has made any changes requiring other Bindings to be updated.

In this case, that creates a bit of an issue, since the `$digest` will never be stable.  every call to the `$digest` generates a new `randomJoke`, which causes the `$digest` to fire again.  If you review the `infdig` error, you can actually see the `Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations` showing 5 different jokes in the `oldVal` and `newVal`.

The `infdig` error is actually a failsafe, angular stops the digest after 10 iterations, to ensure that you don't lock the browser up completely.  In practice, you *could* use the code this way, but the application would suffer from some very poor performance as a result.

The better method is to bind to a variable that is assigned to the result of your function call, which is evaluated once, during controller initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like binding to function is the culprit which causes the infinite digest cycle: [Explanantion](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20oneTimeWatch%22,%22newVal%22:%22We%20are%20out%20of%20doritos%20:-%2F%22,%22oldVal%22:%22%5B%3FBUG%3F%5D%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20oneTimeWatch%22,%22newVal%22:%22We%20ate%20a%20bunch%20of%20doritos%20and%20now%20the%20page%20is%20blank...%22,%22oldVal%22:%22We%20are%20out%20of%20doritos%20:-%2F%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20oneTimeWatch%22,%22newVal%22:%22%5B~~HUG~~%5D%22,%22oldVal%22:%22We%20ate%20a%20bunch%20of%20doritos%20and%20now%20the%20page%20is%20blank...%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20oneTimeWatch%22,%22newVal%22:%22Have%20a%20hug%20or%20two%20*hugs*%22,%22oldVal%22:%22%5B~~HUG~~%5D%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20oneTimeWatch%22,%22newVal%22:%22Sometimes%20it%20just%20looks%20like%20this...%22,%22oldVal%22:%22Have%20a%20hug%20or%20two%20*hugs*%22%7D%5D%5D)

To fix this, bind to a variable instead: `<article><br>{{randomJoke}}</article>`

And in the controller, instead of `randomJoke()` function, assign a randomly generated joke to a variable:

`$scope.randomJoke = $scope.jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.jokes.length)];`

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UPc3CGhPgyfAWafI92b4?p=preview

Comment: Thank you this answer is more understandable and simple but Claies provided a better explanation, if I could I would accept both answers :)

Comment: Hey, no problems man. Didn't answer just to get it marked as the best answer and yep, his explanation was great.