# AngularJS - Attached function to a $scope

Tags: angularjs

I ran into this problem and i can't explain why so here is the scenario:

**Calling the function scenario 1**

```
<div> {{ rand }} </div>
```

**Scenario 1** This works perfectly fine

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rand = randomiseNumber();
    function randomiseNumber() {
        return Math.random();
    }
})
```

**Calling the function scenario 2**

```
<div> {{ rand() }} </div>
```

**Scenario 2** This also works but it gives me angular error

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rand = function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
})
```

**Error**

[image]

I initial wrote my code in scenario 2 first but notice i was getting error so i solve it by using scenario 1. But i want to know the reason why scenario 2 is outputing error?

Comment: rand() calling in loop or in individual div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent "Error: $rootScope:infdig" when different value each time is intended behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827249/how-to-prevent-error-rootscopeinfdig-when-different-value-each-time-is-inte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop**

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

Same issue are here [How to prevent “Error: $rootScope:infdig”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827249/how-to-prevent-error-rootscopeinfdig-when-different-value-each-time-is-inte).

For more help please look into [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: Ahh i totally forgot that i can click on the error link that will lead me to angular problems. Too early in the morning to be solving problems right now. Thank you

Comment: ohhk , Also I have added the link where same type  of issue.